# Headset button double and single click in unity (Android)

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am developing android app in unity and dont know how to handle microphone events.

Did anyone found a good solution for this?
I am looking for implementation in c#

Comment: Can you edit your question to better explain it?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? And what have you already tried to achieve it?

Comment: I want to click on a headset button and let unity know about it as Event.

Comment: Hi @user3505444 could you find a solution for this?